# Conditional probability in bivariate distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose I have a multivariate normal distribution $N$ for the continuous multivariate RV $X = (X_1, X_2)^T$. It is clear that it has to hold

$\int N = 1$

i.e. probabilities sum up to one.

Suppose I fix a value for the first variable: $X_1 = \alpha$ and thus consider only one "slice" of the bivariate distribution. Let this slice be denoted by $f(x_2)$. If I scale this function with a constant $\gamma$ such that

$\int f(x_2) \gamma = 1$ Is this then equal to the conditional probability distribution: $p(X_2 | \alpha)$?